# Why do cv2.so link two versions: libopencv_imgcodecs.so,libopencv_imgproc.so,libopencv_core.so

Tags: python, opencv

I cleaned opencv-3.1 in ubuntu 16.04,then build 3.3,when

```
ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so|grep 3.1
```

it gives:

```
...
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557321d2a000)
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1 => not found
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1 => not found
libopencv_core.so.3.1 => not found
```

as you can see that cv2.so(from opencv 3.3) linked three **not existed** libs from opencv-3.1

when

```
ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so|grep libopencv_core
```

it gives

```
libopencv_core.so.3.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.3..
libopencv_core.so.3.1 => not found
```

obviously,**two** versions of libopencv_core got linked into cv2.so,can anybody tell me:

```
how do this happened?
how to solve this problem?
```

my steps:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python -c
"import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) -D 
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/user/opencv_contrib/modules -D WITH_QT=ON -D         
WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_IPP=ON -D WITH_OPENNI2=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D 
WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -D WITH_OPENMP=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON -D 
BUILD_opencv_java=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D 
ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_NVCUVID=ON -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON -D 
BUILD_opencv_cnn_3dobj=ON -D FORCE_VTK=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -
D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" -D WITH_GDAL=ON -D WITH_XINE=ON ..

make -j 48

make install -j 48
```

Comment: Why are you installing OpenCV in `/usr` when you're building it from source? You should be installing it in `/usr/local`. Also, remove `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so` before installing new version.

Comment: @Zindarod,it is installed under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ not /usr,and by the way,would you please tell me why linking-to-two-versions happened?